# The process name of "<programe name> is not responding"

Tags: windows, process

I'm running a windows program "**swipcard**.exe" and it crashed some time for some reason. when I click "[X]" to close the program. a window popups with a message: "**COMface** is not responding.. blah blah" and have 2 option: "Close the program" and "Wait for the program to respond".
The question is, I'm running the program call "swipcard". but why the popup message is talking about "COMface"? I try to run the powershell cmdlet "get-process -name COMface" but got an error "NoProcessFoundForGivenName". where is the name "COMface" came from?? I never seen this process name in task manager.

Comment: Did it spawn *another* process (that itself died)?

Comment: Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq **the id of swipcard.exe** } return me nothing. I think it doesn't spawn any process.